# Trying to get value of an option field in Java

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I'm having a bit of an issue with getting the value of a select in java.

This is the code inside of my java controller:

```
String topicName = request.getParameter("select_topic");
```

This is the code inside of my JSP file:

```
<select class="topic-form" name="select_topic" style="height:40px; " id="select_topic">
    <option>Select topic</option>
</select>
```

I'm generating options for the select dynamically and then trying to get the selected option inside of java. The problem is I tried to see what the code in java returns and it's a "null"  value. I've also made the jsp return the values inside the console to check if the values are right and they are. So all I can think of is that the value somehow doesn't get taken by        topicName. I have also checked to see if the function gets called and it does.

Comment: Is the select element inside a form that is submitted, or...?

Comment: as said this code would run if it's inside a submitted form. is it?

Comment: Does your generated `<option>` tags contain a proper `value` attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your JSP page with the form is called "topic.jsp" :

1. Make sure that your <form> tag has an action param (ex. action="topic.jsp")
2. Make sure that each of the <option> tags have value param. (ex <option value="-1">Select</option>

Example:

```
<form action="topic.jsp" method="get">
    <select class="topic-form" name="select_topic" id="select_topic">
        <option value="-1">Select topic</option>
        <option value="1">Topic 1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Debugging :

- It is helpful to set form method to GET so the request parameters will be included in the address bar.
- HttpRequest object has a couple useful methods:

  - request.getQueryString(); // if (request.getQueryString() != null) System.out.println("QS: " + request.getQueryString());
  - request.getParameterMap()  // Map<String,String[]> (Key = form object name, Value[] = respective values)